# JS Countdown Clock on Website Time Zone Issues

Tags: javascript, clock, webflow

I'm not too in tune with the JS stuff for my website designs so this is someone else's snippet of code for a countdown timer.

The problem I'm having is I want the countdown to be a specific point in time. Let's say 6PST on 09/15/2023. But when I have a friend in New York check out the website, it is set to 6EST at the same date.

I need this clock to indicate the same time it hits zero for everyone on the website at that moment.

```
function () {

    var deadline = '2023/09/15 00:00';

    function pad(num, size) {
        var s = "0" + num;
        return s.substr(s.length - size);
    }

    // fixes "Date.parse(date)" on safari
    function parseDate(date) {
        const parsed = Date.parse(date);
        if (!isNaN(parsed)) return parsed
        return Date.parse(date.replace(/-/g, '/').replace(/[a-z]+/gi, ' '));
    }

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
        let total = parseDate(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date())
        let seconds = Math.floor((total / 1000) % 60)
        let minutes = Math.floor((total / 1000 / 60) % 60)
        let hours = Math.floor((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24)
        let days = Math.floor(total / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

        return { total, days, hours, minutes, seconds };
    }

    function clock(id, endtime) {
        let days = document.getElementById(id + '-days')
        let hours = document.getElementById(id + '-hours')
        let minutes = document.getElementById(id + '-minutes')
        let seconds = document.getElementById(id + '-seconds')

        var timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
            var time = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

            if (time.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
            } else {
                days.innerHTML = pad(time.days, 2);
                hours.innerHTML = pad(time.hours, 2);
                minutes.innerHTML = pad(time.minutes, 2);
                seconds.innerHTML = pad(time.seconds, 2);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    clock('js-clock', deadline);
}();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the timezone information somewhere in the date string, for example `"2023-09-15T06:00:00.000-07:00"` for 6 PM or `"2023-09-15T18:00:00.000-07:00"` for 6 PM. (PST is 7 hours being UTC). Once the date is parsed, their browser will automatically treat the time as in their timezone (for example with 6 PM, it would be 9 PM in EST), allowing for the seconds/minutes/hours/etc. to be calculated correctly.

Comment: I am only adding this in case they need even more direction. use this [site](https://www.timestamp-converter.com/), enter the deadline date (in your time zone) in "the Your time zone option" and copy the ISO 8601 version. paste that into `var deadline = '2023-09-15T07:00:00.000Z';`